MoviePy Limit on number of files
I am trying to convert around 300 mp4 videos (from the Ekman-6 dataset) to mp3 audio files. I am currently using MoviePy's VideoFileClip (in Google Colab) to do this conversion:
id = 0

for i in range(6):
  path = directory + folders[i]
  cnt = 0
  for file in os.listdir(path):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    clip = VideoFileClip(path + filename)
    audio = clip.audio
    audio.write_audiofile(to_directory + folders[i] + str(id) + ".mp3")
    audio.close()
    clip.close()
    id += 1
    cnt += 1
    if cnt == 50:
      break

However, when converting the 47th file, I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c6ad7f378072> in <cell line: 7>()
     12     clip = VideoFileClip(directory + folders[i] + file)
     13     audio = clip.audio
---> 14     audio.write_audiofile(to_directory + folders[i] + str(id) + ".mp3")
     15     audio.close()
     16     clip.close()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_audiofile'

I'm not sure what is causing this error. So, I searched online and found another stackoverflow post which said that this problem is caused when the mp4 file has no audio. So, I checked the file that caused the error, but it actually did have audio. To be 100% sure that MoviePy was correctly turning that file into audio, I also used the conversion on that file by itself. This time, MoviePy successfully converted the file into audio.
Why does MoviePy work on that file by itself, but not after converting the 46 files before it? Is there some limit on the number of files/length of video that I can convert using MoviePy? I couldn't find any information about this online.
